# Safari Font Rendering seems to be different than in other browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I have an issue with the following HTML-Tag:

```
<a href="/partner-team/team" class="button button__style--1">MEHR</a>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    padding: 0.2rem 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button__style--1 {
    color: #429a95 !important;
    border: 2px solid #429a95;
    transition: color .3s, background .3s;
    background: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

In Safari I get the following visible using Dev Tools:

[image: Button in Safari]

In Chrome as example I get the following using Dev Tools:

[image: Button in Chrome]

Now I'm wondering why the text in Safari is rendered way more at the top.
Is there any possible solution to get the same rendering on all browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge)?

Comment: And don't wonder about the different text displayed. It's just another language but the same element.

Comment: Some browsers, have more `padding` and `margin` defaults. Try setting `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` in your `CSS`

Comment: margin and padding are both set to 0 on the body already. Doesn't fix it.

Comment: Take http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ to heart

Comment: Thanks Anye. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry. Try this `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: I also added an answer

Comment: Did you get this?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working snippet:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

.button {
    padding: 0.2rem 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button__style--1 {
    color: #429a95 !important;
    border: 2px solid #429a95;
    transition: color .3s, background .3s;
    background: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<a href="/partner-team/team" class="button button__style--1">MEHR</a>
```

All that was done here was adding the following to your `a` tag styles:

```css
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Comment: This doesn't have the expected effect in my case. Seems to be a problem with the font. I'm using the font-family 'Stem'